# InSight's Mars touchdown on 26th November 2018

Tags: mars, nasa, insight

According to information on [Mars InSight Mission](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/) official website, InSight is set to land on November 26 at approximately 15:00 EST (excluding pre & post-landing news conference). I am staying in a SEA country (timezone UTC+8), so the live touchdown would be around November 27 ~4:00? Is it only a verbal status announcement of InSight's 7 minutes of terror on Mars or is a camera view from InSight actually available as well?

November 26 is my birthday, so InSight's touchdown on that day is kinda a meaningful moment for me as a space enthusiast in my lifetime.

Comment: https://www.wired.com/story/how-and-where-to-watch-nasas-insight-finally-land-on-mars/ Unfortunately there's no big screens in `UTC+8` https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/timeline/landing/watch-in-person/

Comment: @uhoh yeah I'm aware of that. But that's fine, I could simply watch the live broadcast from NASA on my mobile. ETA 20 hours to go, cant't wait! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No guarantees, but I get the same result.

Based on its current value, the countdown clock on your linked [NASA InSight Mission page](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/) will reach zero at 2018-11-26 19:53 UTC which is of course 2018-11-27 03:53 UTC+8 or around 4 AM for UTC+8, and I don't think there's any chance that's going to change much now!

I'm also in UTC+8 so I'll be watching as well.

As far as the terror, [The <s>Revolution</s> entry, descent, and landing Will Not Be Televised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGaoXAwl9kw).

There will be monitoring of a tone being transmitted by InSight monitored by both antennas on Earth and by the two MarCo cubesats that have been following InSight all the way. The Doppler shift in the tone will be closely monitored, giving critical information as the landing proceeds.

The MarCo cubesats will use their low-gain UHF antennas to receive signals from InSight and rebroadcast them in real time to Earth with their flat, "pop-up" high-gain antennas to Earth as well. See NASA's [How NASA Will Know When InSight Touches Down](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8385/how-nasa-will-know-when-insight-touches-down/) and also [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26773/12102) for more details:

> During InSight's entry into the Martian atmosphere and afterward, the MarCO spacecraft will receive signals from InSight via the UHF antenna on the bottom, and rebroadcast them as a "bent pipe" transponder to Earth in X-band via the high gain antenna pointed at Earth.

I expect there will be a big screen showing the frequency shift versus time that everyone will be watching. So this is going to be a particularly interesting landing!

- [Why will radioastronomy telescopes be used to listen to InSight's entry into Mars' atmosphere instead of DSN?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32053/12102)
- [How can the two MarCO cubesats remain reliably close to InSight during their six month trip to Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26761/12102)
- [Why would InSight's arrival date at Mars be fixed, and independent of the launch date?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25852/12102)
- [Did InSight take a “mean left” turn on its way to Mars? Is it an out-of-plane maneuver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27111/12102)

Also see answers to [Will there be live HD television from Mars with the Mars 2020 mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31601/12102) for more on the general topic of live coverage of reentry.

Comment: Yeah I was figuring out the timeline for the touchdown event in my timezone, doesn't necessary needs to be the exact time. Thanks for all the interesting references!

Comment: @si_the_nibba thanks for the question, it will be a good reminder to other readers to watch. Happy birthday as well ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your sincere wish! By the way, `November 27 4:00 UTC+8` is on Tuesday (a working day...) so I have to wake up before dawn just for the live touchdown and go for work in the morning later...*sobs*

Comment: @si_the_nibba hmm... that's interesting! I don't know about the timeline of events, if the hours before landing or after landing will be more fun. It's possible that say 20 minutes after landing there will be nothing more to watch or hear for a while, but the hour or two before landing could be much more interesting. You could consider asking a new question about that.

Comment: I'll sure keep that in mind. Anyway, with reference to this link here `mars.nasa.gov/insight/timeline/landing/watch-online/`, NASA will be broadcasting the live touchdown throughout variety of platforms, so it wouldn't be a problem if audience miss out something. On-demand video recordings would be available after the live events are over on selected platforms.